# How to find UserDefined Objects that reference System tables/functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several User Defined Stored Procedures and functions that reference system tables and functions, my purpose is to find such resources and delete them,
I used the below query for one of the SP that I knew has system objects in it :

```
    SELECT d.object_id,
           d.referenced_major_id,
           o.name,
           o1.name
    FROM sys.sql_dependencies d 
    JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = d.referenced_major_id 
    JOIN sys.objects o1 ON o1.object_id = d.object_id AND d.object_id =
                          'ID_Of_UserDefinedSP_That_refers_system_Tables'
```

But it does not returns any system referenced objects, other functions that I tried  :

```
sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities
sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities
```

It would be great if someone has a query to find all the UserDefined functions/Views/StoredProcedures(SP) that reference System tables/functions

Comment: See the "Remarks" section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks  Dependency information is not created or maintained for rules, defaults, temporary tables, temporary stored procedures, **or system objects**

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns view type dependency information, stored procedures, functions, and connections to entity classes.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  AS sd
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON o.object_id = sd.referencing_id
```

**get all procedure**

```
Select * from sysobjects where type = 'p'
```

**get all view**

```
Select * from sysobjects where type = 'v'
```

**get all function**

```
SELECT
     name AS 'Function Name',
     SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS 'Schema',
     type_desc AS 'Function Type', 
     create_date AS 'Created Date'
FROM
     sys.objects
WHERE
     type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%';
```

***get all procedure with dependencies***

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  AS sd
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON o.object_id = sd.referencing_id where type = 'p'
```

Comment: It is not what I am looking for, My StoredProcedure has system tables, but when I run this, this query on my stored procedure it does not returns those tables.

Comment: I updated the answer. See you get your answer.